# Decoding json from google firebase rest api using Dart, not Flutter

Tags: json, rest, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

I can retrieve a list of documents from a collection in a Cloud Firestore instance, in Firebase.  The response contains the most verbose json I have ever seen.  Here is a taste, ...

```
{
  documents: [
    {
      name: projects/myprojectId/databases/(default)/documents/mycollection/0HC2spBFxEMNUc8VQLFg,
      fields: {
        name: {
          stringValue: Jim's Bait Shop},
          taxId: {
            stringValue:
          },
          mailingAddress: {
            mapValue: {
              fields: {
                streetAddress1: {
                  stringValue:
                }
              },
              streetAddress2: {
                stringValue:
              },
              state: {
                stringValue: NC
              },
              city: {
                stringValue: Boone
              },
              zipCode: {
                stringValue:
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      createTime: 2020-08-31T19
      :
      54: 28.643464Z,
      updateTime: 2020-09-01T02
      :
      35: 08.203028Z
    },
    {  ...
```

When trying to use jsonDecode, in dart:convert, it fails to de-serialize the json response into a collection of Dart objects.

```
'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

And if I use cUrl instead of Dart, the json response looks just as verbose.

I'm using the FirebaseClient in "package:firebase/firebase_io.dart" to authenticate and read the collection.

I tried to build a "reviver" function but jsonDecode would not accept it so I'm not sure how I messed that up.

Anyway, I'm not seeing much guidance in the documentation on how to marshal this verbose json response into Dart objects.  I suspect this server-side Dart is somewhat new territory.  I want to avoid packages that require Flutter because I'm using a prebuilt docker image, with the Dart runtime preinstalled, on Google Cloud Run.  (Truthfully, I've already tried a few Flutter packages for Firestore and a Flutter docker image.)  I'll take any suggestions you have.

Below is the file I've been using for testing.

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase_io.dart';
import 'credentials.dart'; // borrowed from a SO post
import 'dart:convert';

const base = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/';

void main() async {

  // get private key... 
  final credential = await Credentials.fetch(); // string

  final fbClient = FirebaseClient(credential);

  final path = base + 'my_project_id/databases/(default)/documents/my_collection'
  '?mask.fieldPaths=name&mask.fieldPaths=taxId&mask.fieldPaths=mailingAddress&orderBy=orgId';

  final response = await fbClient.get(path);

  print(response);

  final orgs = jsonDecode(response); // unhandled exception

  fbClient.close();
}
```

I think I might need to switch to a more sophisticated json deserializer package, and annotate my model classes to explicitly map this gnarly json to specific Dart class properties.  But I have not yet seen a Dart package that supports such capabilities.

I have tried to use "json_serializable: 3.4.1" but failed to get code generation to work.

An online json validator is saying the response is malformed due to an apostrophe but can I trust that?  Doubt I can escape special chars.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to stop using FirebaseClient, because it was not wrapping the name-value pairs in double quotation marks. Just use normal http instead.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const base = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/';

void main() async {
  //    
  final uri = base + 'myproject/databases/(default)/documents/mycollection' +
      '?mask.fieldPaths=name&mask.fieldPaths=taxId&mask.fieldPaths=mailingAddress&orderBy=orgId&alt=json';

  var response = await http.get(uri);
  // print(response.body);
  var json = jsonDecode(response.body)['documents'] as List;
  List l = json.map((o) => MyModelClass.fromJson(o)).toList();
```

https://pub.dev/packages/http

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that `response` is not a `String`, it's a `Map`.
That means that Firebase has already parsed the JSON for you and returns the *parsed* structure.

You don't need to use `jsonDecode`, just `final orgs = response;`.

Comment: Thank you!     https://gist.github.com/bwfrieds/123be59320839bb7ca73155577533ee8